# How to bind 4 check box into object with 4 bool properties

Tags: wpf, binding

I have this class:

```
public static class MyData
{
    public static bool val1 { get; set; }
    public static bool val2 { get; set; }
    public static bool val3 { get; set; }
    public static bool val4 { get; set; }
    public static bool val5 { get; set; }
}
```

And i have this array with same variavles names:

```
string[] arr;

arr[0] = val1;
arr[1] = val2;
arr[2] = val3;
arr[3] = val4;
arr[4] = val5;
```

And my `Check Boxs`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox
        Name="cbval1"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="Black"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox
        Name="cbval2"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="Black"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox
        Name="cbval3"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="Black"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox
        Name="cbval4"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="Black"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox
        Name="cbval5"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="Black"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

So when my application is starting i am read some fil and then i have this `string[]` with all those values and i want to `select/unselect` my check boxes according those values.

Any ideas ?

Or maybe i can bind it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MVVM version of that binding. 
 1. Xaml code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxDataModels}">
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soCheckBoxsListboxHelpAttempt:CheckBoxDataModel}">
                    <CheckBox 
                        Name="cbval2"
                        Content="{Binding Title, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsItChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        FontSize="14"
                        Foreground="Black"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

2. View model code:

```
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDataModel> CheckBoxDataModels { get; set; }
```

3. Model code:

```
    public bool IsItChecked
    {
        get { return _isItChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isItChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

4. View Model Initialization:

```
private void InitDataContext()
    {
        DataContext = new MainViewModel
        {
            CheckBoxDataModels = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDataModel>(new List<CheckBoxDataModel>
            {
                new CheckBoxDataModel
                {
                    IsItChecked = true,
                    Title = "first"
                },
                new CheckBoxDataModel
                {
                    IsItChecked = false,
                    Title = "second"
                },
                new CheckBoxDataModel
                {
                    IsItChecked = true,
                    Title = "third"
                },
                new CheckBoxDataModel
                {
                    IsItChecked = false,
                    Title = "first"
                }
            })
        };
    }
```

5. How it is look like:
   [image]

   regards,